# Binary Search Tree (BST) - Traversal search

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-search-tree, function-pointers

Write a function that, efficiently with respect to time used, returns 1 if a given binary search tree contains a given value, else 0.

For example, for the following tree:

- n1 (Value: 1, Left: null, Right: null)
- n2 (Value: 2, Left: n1, Right:n3)
- n3 (Value: 3, Left: null, Right: null)

Call to contains(&n2, 3) should return 1 since a tree with root at n2 contains number 3.

The function should return 1, however, it returns 0 or nothing at all.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;

int contains(const Node *root, int value)
{
    if (root->value == value)
    return 1;
    else if (value < root->value)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)
        return 0;
        return contains(root->left, value);
    }
    else if (value > root->value)
    {
        if (root->right == NULL)
        return 0;
        return contains(root->left, value);
    }

}

int main()
{
    Node n1 = {.value=1, .left=NULL, .right=NULL};
    Node n3 = {.value=3, .left=NULL, .right=NULL};
    Node n2 = {.value=2, .left=&n1, .right=&n3};
    printf("%d", contains(&n2, 3));
}
```

Comment: At the second else if statment, you're checking root->left again. That should be contains(root->right, value).

Comment: It works! Silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Are you not returning `root->right, value`  when `value > root->value`?

```
else if (value < root->value)
        {
            if (root->left == NULL)
            return 0;
            return contains(root->left, value);
        }
        else if (value > root->value)
        {
            if (root->right == NULL)
            return 0;
            return contains(root->right, value); //You need to go to the right branch 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the else condition you are not going to the right branch, but the left branch.

```
else if (value > root->value)
{
    if (root->right == NULL)
    return 0;
    return contains(root->left, value);
}
```

Use the line below in the case where value is greater, to fix

```
    return contains(root->right, value);
```